# subfig caption spacing

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

How do I reduce the vertical space between a caption of a subfigure and the image of that subfigure?

I tried:

```
\subfigure[\vspace{-0.2in} caption words]
```

doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: »subfigure« is obsolete. Its official successor is »subfig«, but this isn't maintained any more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
\addtolength{\subfigcapskip}{-0.2in}
```

You can read about customizing subfigure layout in Section 4 of the [subfigure manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf).

Comment: Subfigure is obsolete as far as I know. It has been superseded by subfig.